# kendo ui tooltip for custom command

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Hello Everyone,
             I am using kendo ui tooltip to display the content of the fields. It's working fine, but the problem is with custom command of the grid. I show only the icon for the custom command(like edit or remove buttons) without any text. If I want to show what the icon represents on mouse over on the button its displaying empty box. Any help how to overcome this issue and display the text in the tooltip.

```
command: [{ 
    name: "e", 
    text: "", 
    title: "Update User Details", 
    Class: "test", 
    imageClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil", 
    click: EditUserInfo 
}, { 
    name: "destroy", 
    text: "", 
    title: "", 
    imageClass: "k-icon k-delete" 
}]
```

Tooltip code:

```
$(document).kendoTooltip({
            filter: 'span',
            content: function (e) {                   
                var target = e.target; // the element for which the tooltip is shown
                return target.text(); // set the element text as content of the tooltip
            },
            width: 160,               
            position: "top"
        }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward **here is the link** (http://jsfiddle.net/xaXPV/) Think this might give you better understanding regarding my question. No text is displayed in the tooltip on the mouseover on custom command in the grid. **Note**: if use  text attribute in the command tag it displays text on the button. i don't want to display text on the button, only in the tooltip. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The element have no text to show so it'll be empty what you wanno show? The image like: http://jsfiddle.net/xaXPV/1/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward thats great stuff! i forgot to add one more, so updated (jsfiddle.net/vkpaidisetty/xaXPV/3) i want to show the title(update).

Comment: You want to get the column header and set it as tooltip text?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward yeah.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xaXPV/4/; if ok I'll add it as answer

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward that's great effort! what if there are more than one command button's(for exe remove, refresh..) and kendo builds most of the images dynamically.(http://jsfiddle.net/vkpaidisetty/xaXPV/6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try check you kendo grid definition and if the current element has the classes of the cell icon show its title.

Code:

```
$(document).kendoTooltip({
    filter: "span", // if we filter as td it shows text present in each td of the table

    content: function (e) {
        var grid2 = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var retStr;
        $.each(grid2.columns[3].command,function( index, value ) {            
            if (e.target.hasClass(value.imageClass)){
                retStr=value.title;
                return false
            }            
        });
        return retStr

    }, //kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    width: 160,

    position: "top"
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QM3p7/

Comment: **its Perfect**. Thank you for your help and your patience for answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Ver").Click("showDetails").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Vista Rapida" })).Width(50);
```